# How to get the shell function's output in slime?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

In REPL, we can get its output normally:

```
(shell "head -3 ~/misc.lisp")
(asdf:make-build 'stumpwm :type :program :monolithic t
             :move-here "."
             :name-suffix ""
```

However, we get nil from `(shell "head -3 ~/misc.lisp")` in slime.

Sincerely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use #'run-shell-command instead of shell:

```
(let ((str (ext:run-shell-command cmd :output :stream)))
    (loop  for line = (read-line str  nil)
        until (null line)
        do (print line)))
```

it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Lisp implementation you're using, but normally you should need a package to run shell command like:

- [trivial-shell](http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-shell/)
- [inferior-shell](http://www.cliki.net/inferior-shell)
- [clesh](https://github.com/Neronus/clesh) (build on top of trivial-shell)